# Route url not found after build

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

The route is working fine on local. However, it is not working after the build except the home route which is working but the two route it gives 404 not found result. The login and registration component its a plain form not connected to any API or server and the home component its just a return plain text info.
I'm new to react so I don't know an idea why not working on build but perfectly working on development.

I tried to run both on serve build localhost:5000 and upload to the server but not working also.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
   Route,
   Switch,
   BrowserRouter as Router
 } from 'react-router-dom';

import LoginComponent from './component/login/login'
import RegisterComponent from './component/registration/register'

import Home from './component/dashboard/template/home'



 const NoMatch = ({location}) =>(
    <div>
      <h3>No Match for {location.pathname}</h3>
    </div>
 )

class App extends Component {

 render() {
     return (
        <Router>
           <Switch>
             <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
             <Route path='/login' component={LoginComponent} />
             <Route path='/register' component={RegisterComponent} />
             <Route component={NoMatch} />
           </Switch>
        </Router>
     );
   }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely an issue to do with how your server is set up. When visit the page, `/login`, the server is looking for a file called `/login` in the root. You need to configure a single entry-point to the server at index.html

In Apache this would be configured in .htaaccess or in nginx you can use a rewrite

Comment: I tried already on my root build folder and htaccess but it gives the same result 
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]